# Changing the dial screen

Tags: android, phone-call

When I dial a number on an Android based phone, the following screen comes up:
[image: Dial a number screen]

Is there a way to ***change*** this screen and replace it with a screen of my own? There are other questions on these lines on stackoverflow, but they have been unanswered. Hoping for some different luck.

Comment: Hi Sriram, did you able to modify this screen using Android code.. Please share code.. i am stuck in designing this screen.

Comment: No. I was not able to do so. I wanted to alter it as an addition to a small application I was building in Android. The project later got shelved. I would still love to know how to do this though. I want to start with Android development again. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You could try some 3rd party applications:

- [ADW Launcher](http://jbthemes.com/anderweb/category/adwlauncher/)
- [aTAKEphONE](http://www.morninpaper.com/2009/01/atakephone-103-for-android-change-the-way-you-dial/)
- [Dialer One](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=637852)
- [NubDial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=629032)

Comment: Mega, did you have any idea how this3rd party applications are developed ? It will be great help if you share some technical solution for the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have. I can only assume they just override the default behaviour concerning the native intents which handle dial communications and such. Fortunately, some of the projects I suggested above are opensource, so you are able to take your tame and learn from their source code. It is a great way of learning Android, specially if the code is well documented.

Comment: Rol no1 - Did you ever figure this out. Im stuck at the same thing....Please help